# Peculiar issue with mutt & my_hdr From:

Tags: mutt

I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure this out and I'm not entirely sure this is a unix issue (perhaps someone could enlighten me)

First off, I started from scratch installing mutt with yum.  Mutt works perfectly if I don't use `set`, but instead use `my_hdr` to setup the header.  Why?  Not sure, but it really doesn't bother me as I prefer `my_hdr` anyhow.  If somebody thinks this is relevant to the issue at hand, I'm all ears for a solution :)

I am familiar with .muttrc, and this is where I've put the following:

```
my_hdr From: root <xxx@xxxx>
my_hdr Content-Type: text/html
....
```

The above works perfectly.  My problem lies with changing "root" to any other value.  (ie: "root1", "john doe", etc...)  Unless this value is "root", no email.  I have a bad feeling that the problem lies with touchy spam filters on the receiving end, but as a last stab I thought I'd post this here for other ideas/views.  Perhaps it could help someone else who is going through the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name part shouldn't affect anything; even DKIM and SPF will only verify the hostname portion of the address.  There may be some other header mismatch going on; it would help to send a mail to a server that you know won't filter it, and check all of the headers to see what ended up in there.  You might also try adding a `Sender: root <xxx@xxxx>` header that matches the sender exactly.  Many spam filters will verify against the `Sender` header but still show the `From` header to users.

Comment: Actually, that seems to work now.  `my_hdr Sender: root <root@localhost>` seemed to do the trick.  I guess if `Sender:` is left unspecified, `From:` is the next call for anti-spam verification?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  From the point of view of most spam filters, as long as `Sender` shows the actual sender for tracing purposes, it's OK to put whatever you want in the user-visible `From` field.